# error with a deleted mysql table belong to laravel telescope

Tags: mysql, laravel

i have deleted `telescope_entries` table by mistake from the phpmyadmin , and i don't know how to restore it,

- I tried remove the package and install it
- I have tried migration
- telescope commands

like:

```
php artisan telescope:clear
php artisan telescope:install
php artisan telescope:prune
php artisan telescope:publish
```

also i have tried to create it as it was found in other project and i got a mysql error

```
#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: have you identified which migrations creates and alters that table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your migrations table,

then delete `2018_08_08_100000_create_telescope_entries_table` migration

and do `php artisan migrate` again

you might need to do `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=telescope-migrations`

you will need to delete `telescope_entries_tags` and `telescope_monitoring` table also, if not the migration will fail